# How can I transform a string to a valid filename in UWP?

Tags: uwp

I'm taking input from a TextBox to use as filename. But this can contain for instance a '/'. When I use this as filename I get an error obviously. How can I generate a good filename?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the invalid characters from the TextBox.Text. 
You can use Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars() to get a Char[] of the invalid characters for file names.

You can replace the invalid characters by a "_" via the following code:

```
var str= TextBox.Text;
var illegalChars = Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars();
foreach (char c in illegalChars)
{
   str = str.Replace(c.ToString(), "_"); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Sander's answer is technically correct, but I would like to add that you might not be able to use that filename in your UWP app.

By design, a UWP application can only access files in a few select locations on disk such as Documents, Pictures, Temp library or the application install folder.
In order to allow access to any other files, you need to have the user pick that file via the FilePickers (both for opening and saving a file)

You can read more about accessing files and folders in a UWP app [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions)